# Basics: Running code in main thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Given that posting a task with `post()` puts the `Runnable` in a queue, is there any difference between

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("UI thread", "Do something");
}
```

and

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("UI thread", "Do something");
        }
    });
}
```

?

In both cases, there should only be one thread running and no concurrency happening - right?

Then what's the benefit in creating a handler that attaches to the UI thread and running tasks on it?

Comment: No, there is no difference

Comment: Actually, the second option will run on the next event loop, so it'll run after onResume - but they are both on UI thread

Comment: Because that'll post it over to the UI thread even if you're not on the UI thread.

Comment: @JohnMunroe Imagine that you have some `background` thread and you want to update `UI` according to some operations in that thread, but `UI` can be updated only on `main` thread. In that case, you can use your handler and post updates to `UI` thread from background thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timing is different. In the first snippet the code is executed as part of the `onCreate` execution so it is guaranteed to finish before `onCreate` returns, in the second snippet, it is executed some time later (maybe after several other callbacks).

Comment: Right. What might be an example in which a handler attached to the UI thread is useful? Why not just run tasks serially like in the first example?

Comment: @JohnMunror Have you ever tried to execute a network request serially like your first example? You'll crash :)

Comment: One example is execution after some time, another is to put in tasks from another thread.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This would not help, the network request would still run on the main thread (or better said not run).

Comment: Yes indeed, which is why now you'll need to run it on a background thread. So then, how do you make a callback to the UI thread once that's complete? With a Handler! Basically I meant that serial execution is just not possible in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Then what's the benefit in creating a handler that attaches to the UI thread and running tasks on it?

Your example provides only a minimal "use case" which most developers may never experience. In your example, you might want to start a background service but you wanted to ensure that the method that starts the service completes before performing that work, your example would accomplish that. Additionally, you might want to ensure that the service construction is prioritized on the main/UI thread. This approach means you don't have to add a comment like "put this code at the end of this method" or have other "inherent code dependencies" - the call to the handler guarantees post-method/end of method execution. Not really "normal" so...

A more useful example is when you have a background thread that needs to update the UI. It can do the necessary processing in the background, then create a handler that will execute on the UI thread appropriately. This is very common and is implemented in `AsyncTask` for example (in its `getMainHandler()` method - https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L282)

Also, handlers allow for post-delayed execution of `Runnable`s. A post-delayed execution is often beneficial for situations where immediate screen display is more important than complete screen display. In most cases a developer should "bake-in" a delay and have the screen show a loading spinner or some other UI/UX decoration, but if there isn't a requirement to specify the length of the delay, the example you gave would post the runnable on the main thread looper queue to execute ASAP. That might be exactly what you want to do, or it might be confusing to other developers that might have to maintain your code (for example, the reason you asked this question).